# Programmatically detect Bouncycastle version

Tags: java, bouncycastle

I am using multiple libraries that wrap Bouncycastle, and it lacks the maven artifact data. I would like to be able to detect the version of Bouncycastle in code. I attempted to find an internal version myself but the library is absolutely massive. Any ideas?

e.g. For Jetty, it is simply Jetty.VERSION.

UPDATE: `new BouncyCastleProvider().getVersion()` is the solution.

Comment: You could fingerprint known class files with a hash signature and detect that way.

Comment: I could, but I would have to hash almost all of it. It is looking like there is no simple way to do what I want. It seems strange that something as sensitive as a crypto lib has no way to do version checking (shy of maven)

Comment: I think you could find one or tow classes that have unique values and settle upon those to fingerprint the version.

Comment: I put up an issue on their tracker, we will see how that goes.

Comment: Well, even if they do add one, I doubt they'd go back retroactively and add to previous releases. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is defined in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` files in each jar. You can view this programatically with:

```
org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
  .class
  .getPackage()
  .getImplementationVersion()
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason all off the metadata is missing from the bundled jar (again, it is brought in via another lib). When I ran the code, it gave me version 2.0.7, but that can't be correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible, unlikely & terrible hack.

If you have the class `org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredOutputStream` available (part of bcpg) you might be able to use reflection to get the value of [version](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/bcpg/ArmoredOutputStream.java#L100). It seems to bake the version number into it at build time.